# docker-compose Django to access postgresql from localhost

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I've a django app running with docker-compose and want it to access postgres installed on localhost

here's the steps I followed:

1- added `host    all             all             172.17.0.1/16           md5` to pg_hba.conf

2- changed listen_addresses to * in postgresql.conf

3- changed db_host to `host.docker.internal`

4- in docker-compose.yml added extra_hosts to the service so it looks like this

```
services:
  web:
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

5- restarted postgresql `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

still getting this error

```
could not connect to server: Connection timed out
Is the server running on host "host.docker.internal" (172.17.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Normally, you don't need to add `extra_hosts` in docker compose. Just set the db host name to `host.docker.internal` in your application. Are you able to connect to the db when skipping `172.17.0.1/16`?

Comment: if I did so, it won't be able to resolve `host.docker.internal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my question

first of all, you need to know what subnet is your network using

list all networks

```
docker network ls
```

then inspect yours

```
docker network inspect network_name
```

get the subnet which is something like 172.18.0.0/16
add the subnet to pg_hba.conf
make ufw accept the connection

```
ufw allow in from subnet
```